# Oracle PL SQL procedure that is equivalent to T SQL in Sequel / Sybase

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sybase

I am new to Oracle. Come from an SQL / Sybase background and struggling to create a procedure that simply should output a set of fields from a table.
I am looking to create a Stored Procedure in Oracle that is equivalent on SQL/Sybase as follows;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListTransactions @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime AS
DECLARE @ReportDate datetime
SET @ReportDate = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(), 103), 103)
SELECT
   @ReportDate,
   trn.TransactionDate,
   cp.CounterPartyName,
   cu.Currency_Name,
   trn.Amount,
   trn.PostedBy,
   trn.Comments
FROM
   Transactions trn
   LEFT JOIN CounterParties cp ON trn.CounterParty_Id = cp.CounterParty_Id
   LEFT JOIN Currency cu ON trn.Currency_Id = cu.Currency_Id
WHERE
   trn.TransactionDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do something like what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LIST_TRANSACTIONS(pStartDate IN DATE,
                                             pEndDate   IN DATE)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
DECLARE
  csr SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN csr FOR
    SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE),
           trn.TransactionDate,
           cp.CounterPartyName,
           cu.Currency_Name,
           trn.Amount,
           trn.PostedBy,
           trn.Comments
      FROM Transactions trn
      LEFT OUTER JOIN CounterParties cp
        ON trn.CounterParty_Id = cp.CounterParty_Id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Currency cu
        ON trn.Currency_Id = cu.Currency_Id
      WHERE trn.TransactionDate BETWEEN pStartDate
                                    AND pEndDate;
  RETURN csr;
END LIST_TRANSACTIONS;
```

I don't understand what you meant by "output a set of fields from a table". This function will return a cursor that the caller can subsequently iterate.  For example, if you wanted to dump the results of the cursor to DBMS_OUTPUT you could do something like the following anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
  c                    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  dtDate               DATE;
  dtTransaction_date   DATE;
  strCounterPartyName  VARCHAR2(100);
  strCurrency_Name     VARCHAR2(100);
  nAmount              NUMBER;
  strPostedBy          VARCHAR2(100);
  strComments          VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  c := LIST_TRANSACTIONS(pStartDate => SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' MONTH,
                         pEndDate   => SYSDATE);

  LOOP
    FETCH c
      INTO dtDate,
           dtTransaction_date,
           strCounterPartyName,
           strCurrency_Name,
           nAmount,
           strPostedBy,
           strComments;

    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date=' || dtDate || 
                         'Transaction date=' || dtTransaction_date ||
                         'Counter-party namme=' || strCounterPartyName ||
                         'Currency name=' || strCurrency_Name ||
                         'Amount=' || nAmount ||
                         'Posted by=' || strPostedBy ||
                         'Comments=' || strComments);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c;
END;
```

Not tested on animals - you'll be first!

Share and enjoy.

Comment: FYI, the funny double CONVERT with @ReportDate is T-SQLs equivalent of Oracle's TRUNC statement. It sets the time portion to all zeros -- i.e. midnight. Although I prefer `DateAdd( d, 0, DateDiff( d, 0, getdate()) )` which does the same thing with strictly arithmetic functions rather than text formatting/parsing.